# Setting up wallet on new machine with 12 word passphrase - next button greyed out

Tags: electrum, passphrase

I have Electrum 2.8.0 on a Mac with a wallet I'm logged into.

I've gone to Wallet / Seed to get the 12 word passphrase.

I then have a Windows 10 PC with Electrum 2.9.3 on. In the install Wizard I type in the 12 words, but then 'Next' button is still greyed out.

Shouldn't the Next button stop being greyed out when I've typed all 12 words (checked multiple times)? How do i restore using the passphrase seed on the new computer?

Answer (score 1):

You can see [this](https://bitcoinelectrum.com/frequently-asked-questions/#why-wont-electrum-accept-my-seed-when-i-attempt-to-restore-my-wallet-from-it) FAQ entry regarding this problem. It covers various possibilities.